# JSON parsing in android

Tags: listview, android-studio

To get certain image from Pixabay i'm using there api.

```
https://pixabay.com/api/?key=****************fae&pretty=true&image_type=photo&q=yellow+flowers
```

where `key` is my api key. But when i add one more parameter i.e. `&response_group=high_resolution` in the url its not showing any result in the listview. And when i remove it its again working fine.

When i try to access the same url from pc along with `&response_group=high_resolution` its returning me the json result.

Comment: What's the json/status response you are getting?

Comment: Nothing in the 2nd case and in the 1st case where i'm not using response_group=high_resolution its giving me json objects and its value i.e listview is able to display the result but it's showing nothing in the 2nd case,nor giving any error.

Comment: Could it be possible that because i'm using httpurlconnection its not properly able to parse it?

Comment: Disregard the listview or UI for now. Just focus on getting the correct response from the server. What are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

To parse an Json you need your result as a String. If you have that you can go ahead like

```
JsonObject data = new JsonObject(resultString);
```

after that you can either get subobjects of that Object or Values

A Subobject (e.g. the object image inside your main JSON)

```
JsonObject image = data.getJsonObject("image");
```

or as I said values

```
int number = data.getInt("random_number");
```

But remember that you always have to try and catch a JsonException.

Comment: You didn't understand.I was able to parse json in the 1st url.But when i'm adding response_group= high_resolution for retrieving Hd images its not showing anything.

Comment: First up, if you dont receive anything you cant parse anything so your questions kind of wrong asked. I recommend you trying to use an official library like Volley. Sometimes things in AsyncTasks get messed up.

Comment: Actually i'm new to android and don't know how to use volley.

Comment: It's much easier than using async tasks, look it up here https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html